# Nginx, URL rewrite: Location or $request?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I need some help to understand the **Nginx rewrite function**.

Imagine, a real file is at the following address:

http://www.domain.com/library/content/folder/country/page/index.html

I want to **rewrite the URL**, to have something better (more human readable!):

http://www.domain.com/page

**1.** How can I do that with **Nginx**?

```
location = /... {
    rewrite ...
}
```

Or

```
if ($request ~* "page") {
    rewrite ...
}
```

**2.** How can I write this rule ?

If I was using Apache, I will write something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^page /(.*) library/contents/folder/contry/page/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the *alias* or *root* instructions in a *location* block

```
location /page/ {
    root /my/absolute/path/library/content/folder/country/;
}

location /page/ {
    alias /my/absolute/path/library/content/folder/country/page/;
}
```

Source: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule

Answer (score 0):

How about

This problem is related to versioning of API based on header

INPUT url : http://abcd.com/v1/getshafts?param=q ,header = v1.1

OUTPUT : abcd.com/v1.1/getshafts/

what should be 'rewrite' value here?